# How to stop executing CodeDom generated code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, codedom

I am currently learning C# in an unconventional way: by writing a program and understanding how it works instead of reading a book, because it’s kind of boring, but I’m planning to do so eventually.
I am writing a program that will compile user created code and execute it. Please excuse me the snippets of code copied from another StackOverflow questions. I didn’t change the names and texts because it’s still being in a proof-of-concept state. The program works well, I am able to execute functions from my main program as well as user defined ones, but I have a large problem: The user (me, because I am writing this program for myself) is always able to write a function that will lock the program (deliberately or not) (for example an unexpected endless loop). I would really like to have the ability to terminate the execution of user generated code. (It would be best to have this option from my main program) The problem is larger mainly because the user generated code has a timer (and can have more timers than one), so just jumping to the end of the user generated Main function won’t do the trick. The application will have the ability to run several user generated codes, by using `Application.DoEvents()` in loops, so it will have a poor multitasking ability. I would really want to stay away from different threads, because, from my “experience” in VB.NET, it is hard to communicate between different threads. I tried using `System.Environment.Exit(0)`, but this ended in closing user generated code (good) and main program (BAD).

To sum up: I would like to terminate the execution of code, written by the user and compiled by CodeDom, without affecting my main application. Is this even possible? If not, then what can I do to achieve this effect in a different, maybe worse way?

This is my source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace CTFGame
{
    public partial class m : Form
    {
        public m()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Main_entry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            string userCode = txt_code.Text;

            string code = @"
                using System;
                using System.Threading;
                using System.Diagnostics;
                using System.Windows.Forms;

                namespace CTFGame{
                    public class MyPlayer{
                    static TextBox tbox_global;


                    " + userCode + @"


                    private static void TimerCallback(Object o) {
                        MessageBox.Show(""In TimerCallback: "" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    }

                    } //class
                    } //namespace
                ";
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);

            stopwatch.Stop();
            //MessageBox.Show(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            if (results.Errors.HasErrors){
                string errors = "";
                foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                {
                    errors += string.Format("Error #{0}: {1}\n", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText);
                }
                txt_errors.Text += errors;
            }
            else{
                Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;

                Type program = assembly.GetType("CTFGame.MyPlayer");
                MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod("Main");

                main.Invoke(null, new object[] { txt_box });
                MessageBox.Show("end of execution");
            }
        }



        public static void tst() {
            MessageBox.Show("It works :)");
        }

    } //class
}  //namespace
```

This is my WinForms layout:
[image: My layout]

TextBox tbox is used to communicate between user generated code and main application. It’s dodgy, but it works…
Any help is greatly appreciated .

Comment: sometime, if you add too many restrictions, they reduce the number of possible solutions to zero. you can try to study some open-source IDE code, e.g. SharpDevelop and find out how execution debug functions (pause/termination) are implemented there. I expect it will be sufficiently complicated code

Comment: So it's _not possible_ to stop executing a CodeDom generated code?

Comment: If there are no solutions to my problem, then what can I change to have some solutions?